# How to delete some Tkinter lables from the list and display only remaining one

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, label

/
Hi Guys !

Currently I’m trying to learn Python and Tkinter module.

My problem:

I have a list of label names. For each label which I’m creating in for loop, I’m assigning name from that list , putting them in new labelList and showing them in window. 
After, I need to be able to delete one of this labels from window by my choice (for example: Labels which have names “test2” and “test3” - I want to remove, but “test1” should still be displaying). How can I do that?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("640x480")
root.resizable(0, 0)

labelNames = ["test", "test2", "test3"]  # list of Label Names
labelList = []  # List of Labels

for labelName in labelNames:
    myLabel = Label(root, text=labelName)
    labelList.append(myLabel)
    myLabel.pack()


for label in enumerate(labelList):
     label[1].destroy()  #I need to be able to remove label from window (by my chose), but instead it removing all of them.

root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: Use dictionary instead of list to save the labels.  Then you can use the name to lookup the label.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks! If it’s possible could you please demonstrate some example . How to generate Labels dynamically with different text , safe them to dictionary and after display them by key value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dictionary` to save the labels using its name as key and then you can look up the label by its name.  Below is a sample program:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('640x480')
root.resizable(0, 0)

lbl_frm = tk.Frame(root)
lbl_frm.pack()

# create the labels and save them to a dictionary
label_list = {}
for i in range(100):
    name = f'test{i+1}'
    lbl = tk.Label(lbl_frm, text=name, width=8)
    lbl.grid(row=i//10, column=i%10)
    label_list[name] = lbl

frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(frm, width=10)
entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, pady=5, padx=5)

def delete_label():
    name = entry.get().strip()
    if name:
        if name in label_list:
            print(f'label {name} deleted')
            label_list[name].destroy()  # use .grid_forget() if you want to recover the label
            label_list.pop(name) # don't remove label from dict if you want to recover it
        else:
            print(f'label {name} not found')

tk.Button(frm, text='Delete Label', command=delete_label).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is so awesome ! Thank you so much !!!! Exactly what i have been looking for.